# Oracle: Granting Object Privilages

Tags: oracle11g

I have logged in as system and have created a user by name DEMO.

There is another connection Myconnection. Under Myconnection there is a table 
Dept;  I am still connected to database with SYSTEM connection.

Now when I execute the query

**GRANT select
ON DEPT
TO demo**       it  says table does not exist. How to fix this?!!

Comment: I got the answer.  It should have been GRANT SELECT ON ***SCOTT.DEPT*** TO DEMO.

Comment: It would be better to connect as Scott to grant privileges from that schema to someone else; routinely connecting and doing things as SYS or SYSTEM is a bad habit to get into. Only use the built-in accounts for database maintenance tasks.

Comment: @ Alex Poole : Ok. I will follow that.